# Pass authentication headers when opening a new url

Tags: django, reactjs, authentication

I will roughly describe the problem:

I have a `React.js` application, which authenticates using `IDAM` and receives a token. I can use this token to make requests to the backend API. Everything is fine regarding the interaction `React.js` <-> `API`.

Now I need to redirect to a `Django` application from the `React.js` application. I already have the authentication token, and I want to pass it to the `Django` application. I was thinking about putting the authentication header when doing `window.open` to open the `Django` url, but I realize that it is not possible to put headers with `window.open`.

How can I pass the authentication headers when opening a new url?

### NOTE

The API and the Django application are not related (they are different applications).

- The API is a REST API (implementation irrelevant), used by the React.js frontend to request data.
- The Django application is "normal" Django application (no DRF), unrelated to both the API and the React.js frontend

Comment: maybe you can store the token in local storage?

Comment: @ruddra huh? That has nothing to do with making the django application (running in the backend), aware of the authentication token.

Comment: Okay, I misread. Um, I don't think there is any way to send the header(maybe my lack of knowledge). But you can send the token as querystring params in url, and catch it in Django using `request.GET.get(...)`. For making things DRY, maybe write a mixin for that. IMHO, using DRF and normal django in same project might not be a good design architecture. You should stick to either one of them. :)

Comment: @ruddra thanks. Some remarks. First: I didn't say I am using DRF. I said the Django app **is not** DRF. I didn't say anything about the API (on purpose). Second: even if I wanted to do everything with DRF, the admin is a django app.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using REST API or Graphql, then consume the APIs from React. The POST, GET, DELETE, etc methods must send X-Token header with the http call. The backend must verify the token, if token is valid, and role has the required privileges, then your backend serves the API.

Comment: This is not about an API call. As mentioned, that already works fine. I am asking about a full redirect.

Comment: Ok, then you need to do SSO, maybe OAuth2

Comment: Already done, on the React app. I have the token there. How do I pass it to the django application, so that the SSO does not need to be triggered again from the Django webapp?